# Amazon aws-cpp-sdk Index Faces giving segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, aws-sdk-cpp

I'm having a problem with [Index_Faces](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/aws-cpp-sdk-rekognition/include/aws/rekognition/model/IndexFacesRequest.h) using Amazon **aws-cpp-sdk**. I'm getting **segmentation** fault in following program.

```
Image *fileData;

Image& imageToBytes(const char* str)
{
    FILE *fp;
    size_t length = 0;

    fp= fopen(str, "rb");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    length= ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    fileData= (Image*)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
    fread(fileData, length, 1, fp);
    return *fileData;
}

int main()
{
   Aws::SDKOptions options;

   Aws::InitAPI(options);
   {
       RekognitionClient *rekClient = new RekognitionClient();
       CreateCollectionRequest *clRequest = new CreateCollectionRequest();

       CreateCollectionRequest str = clRequest->WithCollectionId("collection7981");

       CreateCollectionOutcome respose = rekClient->CreateCollection(str);
       std::cout<<"Collection Successfully Created..."<<std::endl;

       IndexFacesRequest iFaceRequest;

       iFaceRequest.WithImage(imageToBytes("/home/msc/Profile_Pics/ms.JPG"));

   }
   Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
   return 0;
}
```

So, how to provide an image file from my local system to amazon aws-cpp-sdk?

Comment: What is `Image`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Image is a class of aws-cpp-sdk.

Comment: It would be clearer if it was in a namespace. Anyway, is it designed to be allocated with malloc?

Answer (score 3):

You can't create c++ classes with `malloc`(well actually you can but you need to call the constructor afterwards). You need to use `new` instead which calls the constructor for you.

There are 4 different classes called "Image" in aws-cpp-sdk, none of them are suitable for passing directly to `fread`.

Comment: Is there any way to pass image to IndexFacesRequest class?

Comment: did you read the documentation? I'm not familiar with the aws SDK myself.

Comment: You don't need to call `new`. You can just instantiate an object and be done.